# Помощь с выражением preg_match php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите пожалуйста, как добавить в условие только латинские буквы, цифры, знак =, знак + и /

Пока что сделал так...

```
if(preg_match("/[^0-9A-Za-z=/\]/", $guild_id_encrypt))
```

Comment: Вот замечательный онлайн сервис по тестированию и в целом изучению регулярных выражений, очень советую: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Книга «Регулярные выражения» Джеффри Фридл, если интересно больше и точно узнать про регулярки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В символьном классе `[...]` перечисляете допустимые символы:

> `a-z` - диапазон от a до z
>
> `/+=` - символы, означающие сами себя
>
> `\d` - цифры от 0 до 9

И ограничиваете поиск началом и концом строки `^` и `$` соответственно. Ну и для регистронезависимого поиска установите модификатор `i`:

```
$guild_id_encrypt = 'Text';

if (preg_match('~^[a-z/+=\d]+$~i', $guild_id_encrypt)) {
    echo 'True';
}
```